# what is error in this code: C++ Check Whether Number is Even or Odd

Tags: c++

I wrote the code below in c++ Check Whether Number is Even or Odd.
When a user input 25 or 11 the program identifies it as an even number it seems that it took only if and neglect else statement[image]

Comment: return value offf n in even()

Comment: *Please* don't post images of code. Post code as *text*.

Comment: You don't return any value from your `even()` function, and if so it should be a `bool` rather than `int`.

Comment: Yor `even` function never returns anything. Your code has Undefined Behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

`even()` inputs `n` from the user, but doesn't return it. Add a return statement at the end and you should be OK:

```
int even()
{
    int n;
    count << "input number:" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    return n; // Here!
}
```

Comment: But then the purpose of `even()` is pretty confusing. It should be rather called something like `inputNumber()`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yup, probably. I stuck with the OP's code and just pointed out the programming error.

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want is:

```
bool even(int number) {
    return (number % 2) == 0;
}

int main() {
    int n;
    std::cout << "input number:" << endl;
    std::cin >> n;
    if(even(n)) {
        std::cout << "The number is even." << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "The number is odd." << std::endl;
    }
}
```

As mentioned your `even()` function missed to return a value at all (which causes *undefined behavior*).

Though even (no pun!) if you get that right the only purpose of your `even()` function seems to get an input value and not calculating anything about the nature (*even*/*odd*) of that value.
This might be quite confusing for anyone reading your code.

If you just want to have a function to take input just name it so:

```
int takeNumberInput() {
 // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    int n;
    count << "input number:" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    return n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your even() function doesn't have a return. If you want to keep the format I'd suggest your replace your even() with getInput().

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout; using std::cin; using std::endl;
int getInput(){
    int theInput;
    cin >>theInput;
    return theInput;
}
int main(){
    int number;
    std::cout << "input number:";
    number = getInput();
    if(number%2 == 0) {
        cout << "The number is even." << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "The number is odd." << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problems are

```
1)
if (num |%2 == 0)       //This line won't even compile. There is a syntax error
2)
int even() not returning a value.
```

Make sure your code compile, and then post it again.